# Use OR in formula TEXT

Tags: formula

Is there a chance to use OR in formula TEXT ? I need to get the value if account record type is ABC then display field from Account.Abc__r.Name or if Account Record type is equal XYZ then dispaly Account.XYZ__r.Name

Could someone help me ?

```
IF( Account.RecordType.Name = "ABC",  Account.ABC__r.Name, null, 
IF( Account.RecordType.Name = "XYZ",   Account.XYZ__r.Name , null))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OR` function does not help you at all here. Nesting `If` functions is one valid way to execute this logic, though the `CASE` function uses fewer formula characters:

```
CASE(
    Account.RecordType.Name,
    "ABC", Account.ABC__r.Name,
    "XYZ", Account.XYZ__r.Name,
    null
)
```